# Solving for the quantile of a probability density function.

Tags: calculus, logarithms, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions, quantile

What is the quantile, p, from the density $e^{-x}(1+e^{-x})^{-2}$?

I believe I am on the right path to the solution, but I am stuck part way through.

I figure that the CDF is almost certainly $(1+e^{-x})^{-1}$.

So to start, then we must have $(1+e^{-x})^{-1} = p$, which I have managed to rearrange as $-ln((1-p)/p) = x$.  The concern that I have is that the question is multiple choice, and none of the solutions match the solution I have arrived at.

So there must be some crucial insight that I have overlooked in the process of the trying to resolve this, that or the CDF I have arrived at is incorrect.

For reference, the choices are:

$p/(1-p)$

$(1-p)/p$

$ln((1-p)/p)$, which is the solution that most closely resembles mine were it not for the fact that is its negative.

$ln(p/(1-p))$

$1/(1+e^{x})$

Comment: Nothing wrong with your work so far. 
You're just not finished. Remember $\ln(x^{-1}) = -\ln(x)$.

Comment: My work doesn't include a $ln(x^{-1})$ term, although that is a good thing to remember.

Comment: If you take the _general formula_ $\ln(a^{-1}) = -\ln(a)$, which holds for any positive $a$, and replace $a$ with $(1-p)/p$, then what do you get?

Comment: Ok, I think I see where this is going.  You get $ln((1-p)(p^{-1}))$, which can be restated as $ln(1-p) + ln(p^{-1})$.  From here, I can get to $ln(1-p) - ln(p) = -x$.  But after that I don't see how I can resolve it further.  I'm stuck at $p = (-e^{p}-e^{x})/e^{x}$.  I'll keep trying on my own, but I'm afraid I need another hint.

Comment: There isn't really a way to give another hint.  I've posted an answer in line with my hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting $a = (1-p)/p$ in the general formula $\ln(a^{-1})=-\ln(a)$, you have

$$x = -\ln((1-p)/p) = \ln\left(\left(\frac{1-p}p\right)^{-1}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like I was overthinking it, how embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define your pdf completely, that is
$$f(x)=e^{-x}(1+e^{-x})^{-2}$$
for $-\infty < x <\infty $. You have to find $a$ such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{a} e^{-x}(1+e^{-x})^{-2} \, dx = p.$$
Thus
$$ \frac{e^a}{e^a+1}=p.$$
Can you solve for $a$?
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{da}\left( \frac{e^a}{e^a+1} \right) &=\frac{\left(\frac{d}{da}e^a\right)(e^a+1)-\left[\frac{d}{da}(e^a+1)\right]e^a}{(e^a+1)^2}\\
&=\frac {e^a(e^a+1)-e^a\cdot e^a}{(e^a+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{e^a}{(e^a+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{e^a}{e^{2a}(1+e^{-a})^2}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Wouldn't this CDF derive to $-e^{2a}(e^{a}+1)^{-2}$?

Comment: Please refer to my new edit to my answer.